# My app crashes when linking to another page

Tags: android

Android app crashes when linking to another page

Every time I clicked on the button I created to go to the next Activity, the app crashes.

Here is the code I used:

```
 public void openPictureCaptures(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventActivity.class);
            this.startActivity ( intent );
        }
```

The Activity I am linking to(**EventActivity.class**):

```
public class EventActivity extends Activity {
    //public static final String KEY_MENU_TYPE = "menutype";
    Button CaptureImageFromCamera,UploadImageToServer;


    ImageView ImageViewHolder;

    EditText imageName;
    EditText detailText;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    Intent intent ;

    public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    boolean check = true;

    String GetImageNameFromEditText;
    String GetImageDescFromEditText;

    String ImageNameFieldOnServer = "event" ;
    String ImageDescOnServer = "description";
    String ImagePathFieldOnServer = "image" ;
    //String menutype = "";
    String ImageUploadPathOnSever ="http://getme.com/osunelection/capture_img_upload_to_server.php" ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);


        CaptureImageFromCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ImageViewHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        UploadImageToServer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        imageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        detailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detailText);

        EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCamera();

        CaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
            }
        });

        UploadImageToServer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GetImageNameFromEditText = imageName.getText().toString();
                GetImageDescFromEditText = detailText.getText().toString();
                ImageUploadToServerFunction();

            }
        });

       /* this.menutype = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_MENU_TYPE);
        if (this.menutype == null) {
            this.menutype = "";
        }*/
    }

    // Star activity for result method to Set captured image on image view after click.
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {

                // Adding captured image in bitmap.
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

                // adding captured image in imageview.
                ImageViewHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    // Requesting runtime permission to access camera.
    public void EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCamera(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(EventActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
        {

            // Printing toast message after enabling runtime permission.
            Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EventActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);

        }
    }

    // Upload captured image online on server function.
    public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject ;

        byteArrayOutputStreamObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Converting bitmap image to jpeg format, so by default image will upload in jpeg format.
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStreamObject);

        byte[] byteArrayVar = byteArrayOutputStreamObject.toByteArray();

        final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                // Showing progress dialog at image upload time.
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EventActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",
                        false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
                Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.
                ImageViewHolder.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

                HashMapParams.put(ImageNameFieldOnServer, GetImageNameFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put(ImageDescOnServer, GetImageDescFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put(ImagePathFieldOnServer, ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ImageUploadPathOnSever, HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();

        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }

    public void goBack(View view) {
        Intent  intent = new Intent(this, IncidentMenuActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class ImageProcessClass{

        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnectionObject ;
                OutputStream OutPutStream;
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriterObject ;
                BufferedReader bufferedReaderObject ;
                int RC ;

                url = new URL(requestURL);

                httpURLConnectionObject = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnectionObject.setReadTimeout(19000);

                httpURLConnectionObject.setConnectTimeout(19000);

                httpURLConnectionObject.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnectionObject.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnectionObject.setDoOutput(true);

                OutPutStream = httpURLConnectionObject.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriterObject = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(OutPutStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriterObject.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

                bufferedWriterObject.flush();

                bufferedWriterObject.close();

                OutPutStream.close();

                RC = httpURLConnectionObject.getResponseCode();

                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReaderObject = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnectionObject.getInputStream()));

                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String RC2;

                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReaderObject.readLine()) != null){

                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            StringBuilder stringBuilderObject;

            stringBuilderObject = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {

                if (check)

                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilderObject.append("&");

                stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilderObject.append("=");

                stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilderObject.toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

        switch (RC) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong that might of caused it? I have made some research online and this is the same method most of them used.

Comment: maybe posting the crash log would be useful for us?

Comment: Make sure you have registered the activity `EventActivity.class` in Android manifest file.

Comment: @Amolpskamble, I did that.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's working now.